# Is there a way to let PhpStorm know that a method returns nothing but to throw an exception?

Tags: phpstorm

```
if ($condition)
    $foo = 'bar';
else 
    throw_exception();
echo $foo;
```

For this of code, PhpStorm thinks that `$foo` might not be defined and shows a warning. I have to add `/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedVariableInspection */` to eliminate the warning that I hope there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATM -- nope.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10673 might be a solution (once it will be implemented).

Right now even declaring `throw_function()` with `@throws Exception` does not help (as throwing an exception is just one of the possible scenarios and not an obligation).

Watch that and the following related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7462
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6562

---

Right now I simply suggest to rewrite the code in a following more straightforward and easier-to-read fashion:

```
if (!$condition) {
    throw_exception();
}

$foo = 'bar';

echo $foo;
```

If condition is not met then exit happens sooner (due to the thrown exception) and the code below will simply not be executed. It's much easier to read and understand this way (to follow the code execution flow).

Answer (score 0):

I think PhpStorm is right, because if you don't meet the `$condition` then `$foo` is undefined.

You could declare `$foo` with a null value (or false, or ' ' ...) before the `if` block to avoid the warning (IMHO this is a better solution):

```
$foo = '';
if ($condition)
    $foo = 'bar';
else 
    throw_exception();
echo $foo;
```

Comment: No, if the condition is not met, throw_exception always throws an exception.

Comment: @bijiDango ...and an exception stop the script, so `echo $foo` is never called. But to suppress PhpStorm warning you can declare `$foo` before the `if` or, better solution, rewrite code as @LazyOne suggests...

Answer (score 0):

(See this more as a comment than an answer please)

As atx stated it's because `$foo` is not definied when it's read. This is called an `undefinied read data flow anomaly`. That's not a "problem" of PHPStorm or any other IDE but of your code or in more general of the PHP syntax. The static code analysis in the else-case only see a method call of a method calles `throw_exception`, not the end of the script. Therefore your code looks like this in this case:

```
throw_exception();
echo $foo
```

And then you read an unfedinied variable.

Let's compare this to to a JAVA example

```
public void test(boolean condition)  throws Exception {

  if (condition) {
    String foo = "this";
  } else {
    throw new Exception("");
  }
  // Doesn't compile: foo can not be resolved to a variable
  System.out.println(foo);
}
```

This does not compile at all, because in the line of printing `foo` "foo can not be resolved to a variable". Same when this method doesn't throws an exception but exits the method with a return value:

```
public boolean test(boolean condition) {

  if (condition) {
    String foo = "this";
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  // Doesn't compile: foo can not be resolved to a variable
  System.out.println(foo);
  return true;
}
```

Let's extend the example:

```
public void test(boolean condition, String foo) {

  if (condition) {
    foo = "this";
  } else {
    System.out.println("else");
  }

  System.out.println(foo);
}
```

This compiles and you don't get a warning of the static code analysis because the static code analysis doesn't see an ur-anomaly: `foo` ist definied in the method header, even if it's definied as `null`.

Hope this helps to understand why you get the warning and should always definie your variables.

Comment: Java is different from PHP here because Java's variable is effective only in the brackets scope. That is the true reason why it does not compile.